# JPA+GSON: Queries result in Stackoverflow only after server restart

Tags: java, jpa, gson

We've recently run into a problem with JPA and Queries for  @ManyToOne / @OneToMany Relations resulting in a stackoverflow. But this only occurs when the application server was restarted since the entities have been created

The problem:
When I normally start my application server with my war-files deployed, I can fill my database with some content and query it no matter what.
However, when I restart the server without clearing the database and I try to perform the same queries, I get weird behaviour:

I get a Stackoverflow exception:

java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:224)

at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:84)

at java.io.StringWriter.append(StringWriter.java:126)

at java.io.StringWriter.append(StringWriter.java:24)

at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beforeValue(JsonWriter.java:610)

at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.open(JsonWriter.java:317)

at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beginObject(JsonWriter.java:300)

at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:190)

at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:879)

at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)

at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)

at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
```

[...]

For completeness: My Entities have the following relations:

*Mission entity:*

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mission", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
private Collection<Mission2Mission> children;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
private Collection<Mission2Mission> parents;
```

*Mission2Mission Entity:*

```
@ManyToOne  
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)   
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)  
private Mission parent;  

@ManyToOne   
private Mission mission;
```

This means, that parents know their children and vice versa, but at least the typical GSON Stackoverflow should be avoided by using the retentionPolicy, as parents are excluded.

I dunno whether this whole issue has to do with JPA or GSON but what really makes me wonder is, why this only happens after the server is restarted. It indicates some sort of session-issue, I can't figure out and I haven't found any other thread or issue on this specific problem, so I'll just ask here.

I know there's the lazy and eager fetch types, but using them wouldn't explain, why this issue only appears upon server restart.

Thanks a lot,
Kay

Comment: Added fetchType.LAZY too all the Relations just to be on the safe side: doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally found the answer and it was a pain to find it out:

In Mission Entity I maintained the children and parents in Collections. However, only one of them was to be serialized by GSON, this "parents" was excluded (@GsonExclude = @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)& @Target(ElementType.FIELD), I just mentioned them explicitly earlier for clarification).

The code below is the "wrong" version of the Mission-Entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mission", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)@XmlTransient 
private Collection<Mission2Mission> children;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)@GsonExclude@XmlTransient
private Collection<Mission2Mission> parents;
```

Does any1 else see the problem? The "mappedBy" maps the wrong references. Of course, when trying to retrieve the children of a mission I need to map it into the "parent" field, in order to find all entries, where the given mission is the parent. The same applies to "parents". Retrieving all parents I need to find map the Mission2Mission Entities, where "mission" (the child) is this.

The code above did that vice versa, which lead to possible inf-loops, as the Mission2Mission Entity (see above) did it the other way round and (it REALLY excluded the parent instead of children).

Swapping the mapping-field (mission and parent) worked like a charm. Took long enough to figure out.

Thanks for the input anyway. The caching-hint majorly improved debugging speed here :)

Answer (score 2):

GSON does not support cycles, so that is most likely your cause.  I think the normal way to avoid cycle in GSON is to make the variable transient, I have not heard of @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) working, maybe it does...

You are probably not maintaining your bidirectional relationships (which is very wrong), so don't have cycles until you clear the shared cache.

You could also try to disable caching, or disable weaving to narrow down the issue.

You may want to try other JSON serializers such as EclipseLink Moxy, which uses JAXB annotations and supports cycles.

There is an example here, http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2013/08/optimizing-java-serialization-java-vs.html

Comment: disabling caching leads to the same behaviour as restarting (oh wonder) - I really wonder, where we're not maintaining our relationships, cause we really try to do this in every single place. However, this wouldn't fix the issue but only reveal it earlier.

I wonder why GSON still runs into a cycle. I've put the @XmlTransient to the relations as well now, but this still doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally sending JPA entities "over the wire" is not a good idea for a number of reasons (performance, security, circular reference issues like above, etc). Because of this it's better to use a DTO objects for that. There has been a lot of threads on SO about that, for instance here: [What is a good strategy for converting jpa entities into restful resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874688/what-is-a-good-strategy-for-converting-jpa-entities-into-restful-resources) .